# Regex match domain that contain certain subdomain

Tags: regex

I have this regex (not mine, taken from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/909483/968739))

```
^[^\.]+\.example\.org$
```

The regex will match `*.example.org` (e.g. `sub.example.org`), but will leaves out sub-subdomain (e.g. `sub.sub.example.org`), that's great and it is what I want.

But I have other requirement, I want to match subdomain that contain specific string, in this case `press`. So the regex will match following (literally any subdomain that has word `press` in it).

```
free-press.example.org
press.example.org
press23.example.org
```

I have trouble finding the right syntax, have looked on the internet and mostly they works only for standalone text and not domain like this.

Comment: So what did you attempt then? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's break down what the "subdomain" part of your regex does:

`[^\.]+` means "any character except for `.`, at least once".

You can break your "desired subdomain" up into three parts: "the part before `press`", "`press` itself", and "the part after `press`".

For the parts before and after `press`, the pattern is basically the same as before, except that you want to change the `+` (one or more) to a `*` (zero or more), because there might not be anything before or after `press`.

So your subdomain pattern will look like `[^\.]*press[^\.]*`.

Putting it all together, we have `^[^\.]*press[^\.]*\.example\.org$`. If we put that into [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9ZbCVg/1) we see that it works for your examples.

Note that this isn't a very strict check for valid domains. It might be worth thinking about whether regexes are actually the best tool for the "subdomain checking" part of this task. You might instead want to do something like this:

- Use a generic, more thorough, domain-validation regex to check that the domain name is valid.
- Split the domain name into parts using [`String.split('.')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- Check that the number of parts is correct (i.e. `3`), and that the parts meet your requirements (i.e. the first contains the substring `press`, the second is `example`, and the third is `org`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a regex that matches URLs whose subdomains contain the word `press` then use

```
^[^\.]*press[^\.]*\.example\.org$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cp4ZyE/1)